# how to regex in SQL Redshift

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I have the following url:

```
pro.somecompany.com/#/aquisitionintelligence/competitiveanalysis/overview/website-performance/hospital.org/*/484/3m?webSource=Desktop
```

I want to the `aquisitionintelligence` part and the `competitiveanalysis` part

Also, sometimes I have links like so `/#/insights/reports?types=SC`

How do I get only the `reports` part?

any idea how to do it in SQL?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more sample inputs, and what you are seeking as the output for each of those inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`regexp_substr()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html) for the general problem of a complex delimiter.

For the third part for instance:

```
select regexp_substr(col, '[^/?]+', 1, 3)
```

If you want just the third part using a single delimiter, use [`split_part()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html):

```
select split_part(col, '/', 3)
```

Comment: This works beautifully! Can you explain the special characters and structure? or refer me to a good source?

Comment: @nimi1234 . . . I referenced the documentation on the functions.  The "special characters" are the delimiters.  In the first case, they are characters not allowed in the returned value.  In the second, it is just the delimiter.